# Open PDF in full screen from the command line

Tags: macos, preview, fullscreen, command-line

I've written a simple-minded "take a break" reminder which just opens a PDF notice. This works fine, but I wish I could open the PDF file in full screen mode from the command line. Does anyone know how to do that? Perhaps some `osascript` magic?

```
#!/bin/sh
B=$HOME/Documents/break.pdf
D=3000
while true
do
        sleep $D
        open $B
done
```

Comment: Why not use AntiRSI http://tech.inhelsinki.nl/antirsi/ ?

Comment: @mankoff, for the fun of writing my own...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way. Does anyone know a simpler way?

```
tell application "Preview"
        activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
        key down {command}
        key down {shift}
        keystroke "f"
        key up {shift}
        key up {command}
end tell
```

I wish I could do simply `"osascript -e 'application "Preview" to fullscreen'`.

Comment: You can. At least kind of... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215501/applescript-use-lion-fullscreen